# JavaFx объясните причину появления рамок

Tags: java, javafx, button, gridpane

Добрый день. В прикрепленном рисунке слева скрин запущенного приложение в Intellij Idea, справа - предпросмотр в Scene Builder.

На AnchorPane добавлен GridPane в который, по иерархии вставлены кнопки и текстовое поле.

исходники, кому интересно: 
[Github](https://github.com/captsmile/calc)

Операционная система Windows 10 если это важно.

помню что в других графических оболочках Java такая-же проблема, и приходится эмпирическим путем подбирать значения.

```css
.root{
    -fx-background-color: #383838;
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
.text-field{
    -fx-font-size: 23pt;
    -fx-border-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.button, .button:focused{
    -fx-background-color: #E8E8E8;
    -fx-border-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.button-blue, .button-blue:focused{
    -fx-background-color: #7CAFC2;
    -fx-text-fill: #F8F8F8;
    -fx-border-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.button-orange, .button-orange:focused{
    -fx-background-color: orange;
    -fx-text-fill: #F8F8F8;
    -fx-font-size: 15pt;
    -fx-border-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

исправил это удалением отступов у gridPane

```css
.root{
    -fx-padding: 5;
    -fx-border-style: none;
    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
  }
```